# How to manipulate XHR that happened on the page

Tags: javascript

When some http request happens on a page, I can see all of them on the network tab of my browser.

I would like to get some of these requests on my own script and handle it.

I was thinking something like what I can do with Local Storage, for example, in my code I can write this to get some item: `localStorage.getItem('auth-tokens')`.

Is there a similar way to get one or all of the http requests that happened? Only to get the requests that happened it would be enough for me, do not need to intercept or something like this.

Comment: Short answer is, there is no API to provide you all the requests.  The only requests that you can get handles to are the ones that you explicitly initiate from JavaScript and have handles to.  That would mean calls to `XMLHttpRequest` and `fetch`.  You can't touch requests that you don't start from JS land like `<img>` within HTML (unless you did something like `document.createElement("img")` and attached listeners).

Comment: Only way to get to the requests would be to hijack the XMLHttpRequest object before they are made and inject your own code to keep track.

Comment: @epascarello Do you mean something [like this](https://dmitripavlutin.com/catch-the-xmlhttp-request-in-plain-javascript/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an easy solution, this package: [xhook](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xhook)

With this package I can get all data before of any http request like this:

```
xhook.before(function(request, response) {
        const body = request.body;
        console.log('Roll request:', body);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is no, there is no "XHR history" API defined in any spec or implemented in any browser, similar to the `localStorage` API.

An XHR is an event.  You could create your own datastore to maintain the responses to these events (I would recommend a `Map` [or a Map of Maps] to get similar behavior to `localStorage`), or persist them in `localStorage` even.  However, once the event has triggered the event handler, and that is completed, the event and its data are lost if you do not persist that in some way.

Comment: So, Do I have to make something to listen all XHR events and when one event happens I could take the data and handle it?

Comment: @FábioJunioAlvesSousa You probably want a common wrapper for your individual `readyStateChange` event handlers, which will save the response data into some datastore (might just be a local variable), and then fires the event specific callback.  It may seem like overkill, but I have a sneaking suspicion the behavior you want is similar to the Flux paradigm.  It involves storing a series of immutable states, which get transformed by actions, creating a new immutable state.  In this way you can walk forward and backwards through a history of actions, "replaying" a user's session.

Comment: I just need to know which data the page send into the body of a POST request, I could take the data on the begining of the request or when the request has done.

Comment: @FábioJunioAlvesSousa Oh, well then you want a common wrapper for the thing that makes the call, instead of a wrapper for the response handler.  Same principle though - create a common library/function that handles all you XHR, taking parameters for URL, callback function, post data, etc.  If all XHR requests in the app go through this common function/lib you can save all request data in a consistent manner.